# Yammer Data export API shows HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Tags: curl, yammer

I'm using the Yammer Data export API to extract data to local, using curl to send request.

```
$AT #access token
curl -v --output export.zip \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer $AT" \
  --get --data-urlencode since=$DATE \
  "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/export"
```

As example shown at: https://developer.yammer.com/docs/data-export-api

While it always show the error when request to retrieve data.

```
* Connected to www.yammer.com (192.168.1.1) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
{ [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
{ [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
{ [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
} [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
} [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
{ [data not shown]
* SSL connection using ECDHD-RSA-AES256-GCU-SSA324
* Server certificate:
*    start date: 2013-01-01 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2017-01-01 12:00:00 GMT
*    subjectAltName: www.yammer.com matched
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /api/v1/export HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: www.yammer.com
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer 12252-xxxxxxxx
> 
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Date: Wed, 31 Nov 2015 16:06:49 GMT
< Content-Type: application/zip
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
{ [data not shown]
* Connection #0 to host www.yammer.com left intact
```

The access-token I used belongs to the verified admin, and it's OK to use REST API based on this access-token.

Can anyone give me suggestions about it?

Comment: Why is www.yammer.com resolving to 192.168.1.1?

Comment: No, it resolve to the company's IP

Comment: It looks like HTTP 400 is because the verified admin access token's invalid, which I'm using the found the Yammer App Authorization to retrieve the access token, as describe at: https://developer.yammer.com/docs/oauth-2. Plus checked the current.json, it shows the token I'm using the verified admin token. If there is any other way to get verified admin access token except from authorization_code post? Coz right now this token retrieved is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set $DATE? Is there any debugging information available in export.zip (zipped or otherwise)?

Comment: I've set %DATE, the zip file contains no data but a damaged zip file. I've also tried to use wget, it shows the same error 400 bad request. Additional, when use curl to retrieve .json(REST API) shows correct. I'm thinking if this program needs to run through machine of domain account. Right now I'm running it under external computer.

Comment: What happens if you `cat` the ZIP file? I suspect it's not a damaged ZIP file, rather that the server is sending back an error, which curl is storing in a file named export.zip. If that's the case, the Content-Type header is an error and should be something like `text/plain`.